# Javascript Clock goes negative

Tags: javascript, countdown, clock

http://jsfiddle.net/8Ab78/448/

I attempted to fix it but failed.

```js
function ShowTime() {
  var now = new Date();
  var tomorrow = new Date();
  tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
  var hrs = 17 - now.getHours();
  var mins = 30 - now.getMinutes();
  var secs = 60 - now.getSeconds();
  if (hrs < 0) {
    var hrs = 17 - tomorrow.getHours();
    var mins = 30 - tomorrow.getMinutes();
    var secs = 60 - tomorrow.getSeconds();
  }
  timeLeft = "" + hrs + ' hours ' + mins + ' minutes ' + secs + ' seconds';
  $("#countdown").html(timeLeft);
}

ShowTime();
var countdown = setInterval(ShowTime, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: The code shown doesn't run at all, because the `today` variable isn't defined. Anyway, if you are trying to count down to zero and stop there then **you need to call `clearInterval()`** at that point.

Comment: Also what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @nnnnnn—it seems from the code that the OP doesn't want it to stop at zero, but to start counting down to 17:00 "tomorrow" (with some unusual adjustments to minutes and seconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arithmetic is broken.

Each time the clock ticks, a new Date is generated. If it's say 18:00 then then:

```
var hrs = 17 - now.getHours();
```

will go negative, so you'll do:

```
var hrs = 17 - tomorrow.getHours();
```

but that will produce -1. What you want to do is create a date for the end time, then subtract the current Date from that and resolve the result (milliseconds) to hours, minutes and seconds.

I don't know what the minutes and seconds adjustments are for, they don't make sense to me. The following makes minor adjustments to your code:

```js
function ShowTime() {
  var now = new Date();
  var end = new Date(+now);
  var endHour = 17;
  end.setHours(endHour,0,0,0);

  // If past end, set to tomorrow
  if (now >= end) {
    end.setDate(end.getDate() + 1);
  }

  console.log('Counting down to ' + end.toString());
  
  // Get difference and divide into hr, min, sec
  var diff = end - now;
  var hrs = diff / 3.6e6 | 0;
  var mins = (diff % 3.6e6)/ 6e4 | 0;
  var secs = (diff % 6e4) / 1000 | 0;
  
  // Format and write to document
  timeLeft = "" + hrs + ' hours ' + mins + ' minutes ' + secs + ' seconds';
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = timeLeft;
}

ShowTime();
var countdown = setInterval(ShowTime, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

If you're trying to get a countdown to say 17:30, then introduce an *endMin* variable like:

```
  var endHour = 17;
  var endMin  = 30;
  end.setHours(endHour, endMin, 0, 0);

  // If past end hour, set to tomorrow
  if (now > end) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `clearInterval(countdown);` when you want to stop your timer. As per the clearInterval [docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)

> The clearInterval() method of the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope mixin cancels a timed, repeating action which was previously established by a call to setInterval().

Also, I believe the code you've provided needs to be changed to  `tomorrow.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);` instead of `tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);`

Answer (score 0):

You defined a variable as now and looking for today so its not showing the countdown

the new html is like below

```
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

and the new js will be like below

```
function ShowTime() {
var today= new Date();
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+1);
var hrs = 17-now.getHours();
var mins = 30-now.getMinutes();
var secs = 60-now.getSeconds();
if(hrs < 0) {
var hrs = 17-tomorrow.getHours();
var mins = 30-tomorrow.getMinutes();
var secs = 60-tomorrow.getSeconds();
}
  timeLeft = "" +hrs+' hours '+mins+' minutes '+secs+' seconds';
$("#countdown").html(timeLeft);
}

ShowTime();
var countdown = setInterval(ShowTime ,1000);
```

Answer (score -2):

I found this from my previous note but I can't find the link of questions in SO.

```
<font size=1><p id='demo'></font>

<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script> 
<script>
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    //var insert1="<?php echo $insert1; ?>";
    //var timeout1="<?php echo $timeout1; ?>";
    var insert1="05/23/2017 00:00:00";
    var timeout1="05/25/2017 00:00:00";

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {
        var countDownDate = new Date(timeout1).getTime();
        var countDownDates = new Date().getTime();
        // Get todays date and time

        // Find the distance between now an the count down date
        var distance = countDownDate - countDownDates;
        //var distance = countDownDates;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
        + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

        // If the count down is over, write some text 
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Time out";
        }
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: But, OP didn't asked for php.

Comment: yes, i just edit to exclude the php, it works the same tough.. thanks for those who (down) voted..